# QT6 windows linker error when using Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, qt6

I am trying to build a simple QT6 program using VSCode and MSVC. For this, I have following files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(test main.cpp mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.h)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

target_link_libraries(test Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
    : QMainWindow()
{
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT
public:

    MainWindow();

    virtual ~MainWindow();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I am using MSCV with Kit `Visual Studio Community 2019 Release - x86_amd64`.
My QT6 install is under `C:\Qt` and my Path varable contains `C:\Qt\6.2.3\msvc2019_64`

As I stated in the title, when I set Q_OBJECT for the MainWindow class, I get the following linker errors:

```
[build] mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MainWindow@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)". [C:\Users\Nightbird\Desktop\test\build\test.vcxproj]
[build] mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual void * __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MainWindow@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)". [C:\Users\Nightbird\Desktop\test\build\test.vcxproj]
[build] mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: virtual int __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)". [C:\Users\Nightbird\Desktop\test\build\test.vcxproj]
```

If I remove Q_OBJECT, the project compiles / links and runs. The problem is, for me to later implement Signal/Slot-Mechanisms, I need Q_OBJECT.

Now the linker errors suggest that something goes wrong after MOC creation, however I cant find the mistake I made. Do I have to change something in my CMakeList.txt?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I found out what the problem was...

I rearranged my CMakeList.txt like so:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(test main.cpp mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.h)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets)

target_link_libraries(test Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets)
```

Notice the position of the set()-Commands... That seemed to be it.
Now the output also shows `[build]   Automatic MOC and UIC for target test` ... that didn't show before. So if you're struggling with linker errors regarding MOC, see if this line shows up. If it doesn't, check the order of cmake commands